Connection string ignores userId and pwd provided and logins with the Windows authentication user
In the .net core I'm having a connection string something like this,
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;User Id=AdminUser;Password=Admin;Integrated Security=True,TrustServerCertificate=True
I've added a user as AdminUser to the SQL and for the testing purpose I deleted it.
But even after that it get succedeed and ignores the given UserId and Pwd but instead it should throw me the error something like 'Login failed for the user' but it shouldn't.
I found that the Integrated Security was ignoring the user id and pwd, so I tried removing it and then it was throwing the error like this:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)
---- System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception : No process is on the other end of the pipe.

I've also used the Trusted_Connection=True, but still same issue for it too that stated above.

What .NET version are you using?

Which dbms are you trying to connect to?

.Net 8 and SQL Server

.\\[servername] looks weird to me. why not just servername, or are you really running pipes?

You can't use User ID+Password while also setting Integrated Security=True. If you want to use Windows authentication, you can't specify the username and password. It's not clear if you created a user, a login, or a Windows login when you say "I've added a user as AdminUser to the SQL."

Hey Aaron, actually I need to use the SQL user login to the connection string. And it's logging in with the windows authentication user (which I don't want to use). And when I tried removing Integrated Security=True it gives error which mentioned above

Siggemannen, actually it was just for a reference, the actual server name is .\SQLEXPRESS which is my local machine

what happens if you use localhost\SQLEXPRESS instead of the .\\sqlexpress

Here's the document for sql sever connection string format, and none of them matched your connection string, I'm afraid you shall check it by yourself. And could you pls try Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TestDB;User Id=AdminUser;Password=Admin first?

Have you tried connecting to the database with SSMS on the same machine using that user name and password? (Definitely do not want that "Trusted_Connection" setting for using SQL authentication). Is SQL Authentication enabled on the server? It won't work if the SQL Server instance is only set up for Windows Auth. Also, have you checked that Named Pipes is enabled on the SQL Server instance? Otherwise you should use localhost or 127.0.0.1 for the local machine database instance.

It would help to mention (in the question and title) only the problem that remained.

Like if you have to connect sql server with the Windows Based Authentication then use Integrated Security=True;
Server=server;Database=database-name;Connect Timeout=120;Encrypt=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=True;
Used SQL Server Authentication then Use User ID=usename; Password=password;
Server=server;Database=database-name;User ID=username;Password=password;Connect Timeout=120;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
